# C# String.IndexOf returns only one element when result from list is may

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings, retrieved from the database and what I wanted was to filter from this list to get only list items that have some text contained in them. String.Contain would have been perfect but is case sensitive. I expect many results to be returned but only one is. Here is my code snippet

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
    list = list.Where(a => a.Description.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
        || a.Part.ModuleName.IndexOf(searchTerm) >= 0).ToList();
```

I would appreciate in figuring out whats going on.

Comment: just a note. String.ToLower().Contains(string str) would work so that you don't have to worry about case

Comment: Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @oppassum That's true in English, but it doesn't generalize to all languages the way a string comparer can.

Comment: You're not adding `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to the second `IndexOf` call. Could this be eliminating some expected results?

Comment: As pointed out from several comments, missing the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` was the culprit. Thanks for the comments, they were so helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only ignoring case on the first of the two calls to `IndexOf`. This is probably removing some expected results.

Try adding it to both:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm)) {
    list = list.Where(a => a.Description.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
        || a.Part.ModuleName.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the question I don't not know why you're using indexOf. This is what I would do to get a sub-set of strings from a list of strings that contain some other string thats is case insensitive.

```
List<String> searchTerms = new List<String>() { "abcde","efghi","abCDe","efGHI","jklmnoP"};
var subList = searchTerms.Where(st => st != null && st.ToLower().Contains("bcde")).ToList();
foreach(String output in subList)
{
Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Output:

```
abcde
abCDe
```

Comment: This does work for English (and is easier to read imo), but as @Servy mentioned, it doesn't generalize to other languages as well.